# Volume of self-intersecting polyhedra

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, volume

Is there a method to calculate the volume of self-intersecting polyhedra with Wolfram?

---

I did the calculations by hand taking the coordinates from [this site](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/index.html) for some of them (considering $l=1$):

- $\text{Vol}[U32]=\frac{5}{11}+\frac{159\sqrt{5}}{44}+\frac{5}{12}\sqrt{\frac{5106\sqrt{5}-11003}{11}}\approx$ [11.0921894892289](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SmallSnubIcosicosidodecahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U32']= \frac{5\left(1+6\phi+\sqrt{3\phi-2}\right)}{6}\approx$ [10.331343912](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SmallHexagonalHexecontahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U64]=\frac{5\left(47576\sqrt{10}-71284\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2662496513\sqrt{5}-5871595039}\right)}{319\left(287+118\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{113038+54389\sqrt{5}}\right)}\approx$ [0.88855444066](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GreatSnubDodecicosidodecahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U64']=\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{17-\frac{15}{\sqrt{\phi}}-\frac{8}{\phi}}\approx$ [0.64160129709](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GreatHexagonalHexecontahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U72]=???\approx$ [0.228629952](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SmallRetrosnubIcosicosidodecahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U72']=30\sqrt{\frac{79508651}{2112}+\frac{480024241\sqrt{5}}{28512}}-\frac{12350}{3}-\frac{22075\sqrt{5}}{12}\approx$ [1.73183922](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U75]=???\approx$ [0.7968034087](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GreatDirhombicosidodecahedron.html)
- $\text{Vol}[U75']=\infty$

---

Of the "easy" ones I'm only missing U72 and U75, but even though they have easy-to-manage coordinates I can't separate the polyhedra because they are very complicated.

> For the "snub" ones it becomes complicated due to the fact that complicated values ​​are used for the coordinates, but for the latter two there should be a value dependent only on square roots

Whoever tabulated the values ​​certainly used some numerical calculation method, which is why I was wondering if it was possible to do a more accurate calculation with Wolfram

Comment: Please post at least  an example of  self-intersecting polyhedra by Mathematica code.

Comment: It doesn’t appear to be a numerical calculation as the results are exact.  If you know each polygon and its normal, you can compute the volume of the region contained by the polygon’s projection—and then add (for outward normals) and subtract (inward normals). If the coordinates and normals are exact, you will get an exact volume.  The mathematica code to do this won’t be horribly difficult and a good learning experience.

Comment: @CraigCarter can you give an example of projection with a polygon? (even a trivial example)

Comment: A simple example is a unit cube with its center located at (0,0,1) and with a “top” face at position (0,0,3/2) with normal (0,0,1), its “bottom face” at (0,0,1/2) and normal (0,0,-1).  The two projection volumes are 3/2 and -1/2.  So, a good thing to try is writing some code for one of the vertices oriented along the (1,1,1) direction.   IHTH

Comment: Another thing to try is this.  The divergence of z \hat{k} is 1,  V = \int 1 dV  = \int z \hat{k} .d\vec{s}. so if you integrate z \hat{k} . d \vec{s} clockwise around the edges of each face, you will get those projected volumes. (Up to a constant of integration, which you can find.)